# How to get specific string after and before specific character in swift?

Tags: swift

I have this string: `"lat/lng: (-6.2222391,106.7035684)"`

I only need to get those double data type in that `string`. so how to get just only *-6.222239*1 and *106.7035684* as string variable?

How to get the number in that parenthesis?

So I think I have get string after `"("` and before `","` to get `"-6.2222391"` and also after `","` and before `")"` to get `"106.7035684"`

but I don't know how to get that in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let source = "lat/lng: (-6.2222391,106.7035684)"
let splited = source.components(separatedBy: "lat/lng: ")[1] //separating

let removed = splited.replacingOccurrences(of: "(", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: ")", with: "") // removing

let coord = removed.components(separatedBy: ",") // removing

let lat = Double(coord[0])
let lng = Double(coord[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex:

```
let str = "lat/lng: (-6.2222391,106.7035684)"
let rg = NSRange(location: 0, length: (str as NSString).length)

let latRegex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(?<=\\()[+-\\.0-9]+(?=,)")
```

- `(?<=\\()` is *positive lookbehind*, it looks for anything preceded by `(`,
- `[+-\\.0-9]+` eagerly looks for at least one character or more that are either `+`, `-`, `.`, or a digit from `0` to `9`,
- `(?=,)` is *positive lookahead*, it matches anything followed by `,`.

Now let's use this regular expression :

```
let latitude: Double?  = latRegex.matches(in: str, range: rg)
    .compactMap { Double(str[Range($0.range, in: str)!]) }
    .first

if let lat = latitude {
    print(lat)  //-6.2222391
}
```

In the same way, we can get the longitude :

```
let longRegex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(?<=,)[+-\\.0-9]+(?=\\))")
let longitude: Double?  = longRegex.matches(in: str, range: rg)
    .compactMap { Double(str[Range($0.range, in: str)!]) }
    .first

if let long = longitude {
    print(long)  //106.7035684
}
```

---

PS: I've used forced unwrapping here and there for brevity

Answer (score 0):

You have received some good answers already. But I think I've come up with a more compact version.

You need to care about `-` `0~9` `.` and `,`

The `,` will be considered only for having the two components and then be used for separating them.

See this:

```
let source = "lat/lng: (-6.2222391,106.7035684)"
let allowedCharactersString = "-01234567890.,"
let latLongValues = String(source.characters.filter { 
                            allowedCharactersString.characters.contains($0) 
                          }).components(separatedBy: ",")
print(latLongValues.first!) // "-6.2222391"
print(latLongValues.last!) // "106.7035684"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let source = "lat/lng: (-6.2222391,106.7035684)".components(separatedBy: ")")[0]
let removed = source.components(separatedBy: "(")[1];// removing

//OR
//let source = "lat/lng: (-6.2222391,106.7035684)".components(separatedBy: "(")[1]
//let removed = source.components(separatedBy: ")")[0];// removing


let coord = removed.components(separatedBy: ",") // removing

let lat = Double(coord[0])
let lng = Double(coord[1])
```